# Can resources in one Resource Group be used by another Resource Group?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-group

I am currently working on trying to manage and potentially split apart a Resource Group that currently contains basically every resource we have made in Azure. I am thinking the best split would be by Environment (Dev, Test, etc) combined with which App it is (OneApp, AnotherApp, etc) so like OneApp_Dev, OneApp_Test, etc.

There are a few resources (like a single SQL server instance) that are accessible by resources that would be moved apart from each other into many of the other new Resource Groups like an App vm that would go into each new Resource Group.

It is possible to have a Resource Group for shared resources and let each other Resource Group access that one? Or is that antithetical to the point of Resource Groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, however pay attention in case you're using Managed Identity to make sure the identity will have access on the other resource too.

Also, pay attention to group resources in the same region to avoid network out traffic.